# Ruby function undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby, function

```
def wri(var)
puts var
end
wri(hey)
```

output : `main.rb:4:in`': undefined local variable or method `hey' for main:Object (NameError)`

where is the Mistake?

Comment: well.. The error message is pretty much telling you everything. `hey` is a variable and not a string as you probably intended. Use `wri("hey")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the variable `hey` as an argument to the method `wri()`. You probably want the string `'hey'`

```
>def wri(var)
>  puts var
>end
>nil
>wri('hey')
hey
=> nil
>the_variable_hey = 'hey'
=> 'hey'
>wri(the_variable_hey)
hey
=> nil
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip, it's not necessary to include irb-prompts in your answer and it in fact make the code more difficult to read. So best avoided in future. Anyway this answer is correct so I +1'd.